# Setting properties of parent class in child module nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I believe there is probably a structure issue that could solve this problem, but I'm unsure of how to keep set values for a parent class that calls a method within a module. I have tried to simplify my code as much as possible.

I have a series of tasks that I keep track of in a class and run on an interval. Each task fetches data from a remote database and then processes it. While in this example I am only needing to set task.fetching. There are a couple of other values I'd like to be able to update from within the runner.js file.

I should note that if possible, I'm interested in how to solve this problem as a concept and not specifically in finding some module that can handle running tasks for me.

```js
// task.js
const runner = require('./runner');

class Task {
  constructor(params) {
    this.details = params.details;
    this.fetching = false;
    this.interval = null;
  }

  start() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (!this.fetching) {
        runner.run(this.details);
      }
    }, this.details.frequency * 1000);
  }
}

module.exports = Task;


// runner.js
const run = (task) => {
  fetch(task.url)
  .then(parseData)
  .then(data => {
    if (task.format === 'type') {
      return formatItems(data.items);
    }

    return {};
  })
  .then(items => {
    if (Object.keys(items).length > 0) {
      console.log(`Found ${Object.keys(items.newItems).length} new items and ${Object.keys(items.updatedItems).length} updated items`);
    }

    // *** NEED TO SET TASK FETCHING TO FALSE HERE
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log('ERROR:', e);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`task.fetching = false`... not sure I get the question.

Comment: Wow, you kind of just blew my mind. I don't consider myself a total noob on javascript but I missed a key aspect that objects passed as parameters to functions are references and not values. Where as strings and numbers are passed as values.


After your answer I tested it real quick and then googled and found this article: https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass


Hopefully this helps someone else. Sorry for my completely skipping that part of the book... I was thinking I needed getters and setters to update values inside the class.